# How to get customer/guest user email address without using session in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I'm trying to get customer(login)or guest user email address with sales order model, but it reflects blank result . I have been used this code..

```
$orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $oincid = $orderData->getIncrementId();
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($oincid);
            $order->getCustomerEmail();
            echo $order;exit;
```

Comment: Which event are you using? and where exactly?

Comment: I'm using this in placeorder event

Comment: Where are you calling your code?

Comment: in my custom module

Comment: Try this from this link may be help [How to get name and email address of all the custome](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97901/how-to-get-name-and-email-address-of-all-the-customer-from-beginning-of-the-stor)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In your config.xml file:

```
<config>
<global>
.........
   <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <any_name>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>getEmail</method>
                    </any_name>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
   </events>
..........
</global>
</config>
```

Then in your `Model/Observer.php`:

```
public function getEmail($observer){
   $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   if($order->getCustomerId()){
       $email = $order->getCustomerEmail(); //logged in customer
   }
   else{
       $email = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail(); //not logged in customer
   }

   //your other logic

   //lets test if it is grabbing email
   Mage::log($order->getId(). " - ". $email, null, 'your_name.log');
}
```

This will create a file named `your_name.log` in `var/log` folder when anyone places order.

If everything is ok, then you will see your customer's email in that file.

Good luck.

Comment: this is working fine for guest customer but if i want to check that customer register first time then what about that ?

Comment: Above code works in both conditions. Since this `sales_order_place_after` fires after order is placed, meaning it has also registered customer.

Comment: but for what about new customer register and order product

Comment: I think, when customer register and order product, system has already saved customer. Which is why it will pass `$order->getCustomerId()` condition.

Comment: actually i have to thing 1) customer register and check they have order any product or not 2) new customer order for product

Answer (score 0):

Customer emails are also stored with shipping and billing address of customer. Use below code to get email from billing address -

change  `$order->getCustomerEmail();`

to

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
```

in your code

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- Define sales_order_place_after event in your module's config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
       <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <get_emailaddress_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>YourNamespace_YourModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>getEmailAddress</method>
                    </get_emailaddress_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
       </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Step 2:- Define getEmailAddress() method in your module's model's Observer.php

```
public function getEmailAddress($observer){
   $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

   if($order->getCustomerId()){
    // if order is customer order
    $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
   }else{
    // if order is guest order
    $email = $order->getShippingAddress()->getEmail();
   }

   Mage::log("Email id for order no:- ".$order->getId()." is :- ".$email, null, 'email_address.log');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code in your question is what you are actually using, it looks like you are trying to print the $order variable rather than the Customer Email

**Your Code:**

```
$orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$oincid = $orderData->getIncrementId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($oincid);
$order->getCustomerEmail();
echo $order;exit;
```

**Updated Code:**

```
$orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$oincid = $orderData->getIncrementId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($oincid);

// This should contain the customer email
echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
exit;
```