# How to get name and email address of all the customer from beginning of the store?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, customer

I am working on magento1.7.
Every single order has a customer name and email address saved within it.
 However I guess, Magento only shows these details in the Customers > Manage Customers section if that person has created an account.

If the customer checked out as a guest then their name and email address are only saved within the order in the database.

so I am unable to find the list of all customer.

Is it possible to have **a query that will scan every single order** within the back end and get the customer's full name, their email address and order date ?

I want to **find all the customer who has made orders** (both as a registered user or guest) **from the beginning** of the store..

**Could any one suggest some query ?**

Comment: It's incredible you've accepted an answer that retrieves just the guest users and that is loading the entire order collection just to use a few fields...

Comment: @MauroNigrele Well I have modified that a little bit..from ' * ' to specific columns in array format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the below query for guest customer..

```
    $orderCollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                      ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                      ->addFieldToFilter('customer_is_guest',1) ;
    foreach( $orderCollection  as $order){

             echo $order->getCustomerFirstname()." ";
             echo $order->getCustomerLastname()."<br>";

    }
```

if you put "customer_is_guest" to 0 then you can get the registered customers..

This comes directly from the "sales_flat_order" table .

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely! You can get these fields from the sales_flat_order table or simply using order collection resource that way:

```
    $statuses = array('completed','processing');
    $fields = array('customer_email','customer_firstname','customer_lastname');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
    /** @var $collection Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection */

    // - you can use Collection to filter status (if you want)
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => $statuses));

    // - Use the standard zend select to get just what you need
    $select = $collection->getSelect()
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns($fields)
        // group by email to avoid repetitions 
        ->group('customer_email');

    $data = $select->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

You can achieve this in many different ways but I'm pretty shure that this is the most clean and performant.

If you need to differentiate between guest and customers can use the field `customer_is_guest` or `customer_id` but since the query it's grouping by `email` if an user's placed on order as guest an other as customer you'll never know (at least with this query)